# How to prove this formula to evaluate limits?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

A text says 
For any positive integer n,
Lim x approaching a $(x^n - a^n)/(x - a) = na^{n-1}$
Then it proved it using the quotient obtained by the division of two polynomials and obtained a polynomial and pluhged in x= a as polynomials are continuous to yield the result. Then it also said that the given theorem is also true if
"N is any rational number and a is positive" why how can we prove this because then we no longer are dealing with polynomials ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By a change of variable**:

Let $n=p/q$, then with $x=y^q$ and $a=b^q$,

$$\frac{x^{p/q} - a^{p/q}}{x - a}=\frac{y^p-b^p}{y^q-b^q}=\frac{\dfrac{y^p-b^p}{y-b}}{\dfrac{y^q-b^q}{y-b}},$$

which tends to

$$\frac{pb^{p-1}}{qb^{q-1}}=\frac{pa^{(p-1)/q}}{qa^{(q-1)/q}}=\frac pqa^{p/q-1}=na^{n-1}.$$

Comment: But what if p and q are negative integers n will still be rational but we cannot use previous result ?

Comment: @RaghavSingal: try it and you'll see.

Comment: Why does a has to be positive what if it is negative

Comment: @RaghavSingal: what is $(-1)^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: Okk I understand now